# Regular Expression for space separated words

Tags: python-3.x, regex, email

I am trying to match email footers like

1. Thanks,
2. Regards
3. Thanks & Regards,

with the help of regular expression I am able to get first 2 cases,

```
({language_keyword_footer[0]}|{language_keyword_footer[1]}(.*?)(\S+(.*?)))
```

language keyword footer is the metadata that I have created to add more cases in future,

```
keywords = {
    "en": {'header':["From:", "Subject:"],'footer':["Regards,", "Thanks,","Thanks & Regards,"]}}
```

The problem is when I use this approach it captures only `Regards,` and discards `Thanks & Regards,`

is there a way I can add it to the existing `re` and capture this space separated scenario as well, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the items by length in dedcending order as alternation patterns in an NFA regex engine follow "first matched, first served" principle (see the ["Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager) article). Also, do not forget to escape the strings used as literal pattern inside the regex.

You can use something like

```py
pattern = r'({})(.*?)(\S+)'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(language_keyword_footer, key=len, reverse=True))))
```

The resulting pattern would look like `(Thanks\ \&\ Regards,|Regards,|Thanks,)(.*?)(\S+)` here, and will match `Thanks & Regards,`, `Regards,` or `Thanks,` (in Group 1), then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible (in Group 2), and then one or more non-whitespace chars (with `(\S+)`).

Note the `.*?` at the end of a regex pattern has no effect on the final result.